# What's the difference between percent vs asterisk (star) makefile prerequisite

Tags: make, gnu-make

I'm trying to understand why some Makefiles have prerequisites with `%.txt` and others have `*.txt`.

I've created this folder layout.

```
$ tree .
.
├── hi1.txt
├── hi2.txt
├── hi3.txt
└── Makefile
```

First, I tried this.

```
foo.txt: *.txt
    echo $^
```

And it does what I expect.

```
$ make
echo hi1.txt hi2.txt hi3.txt
hi1.txt hi2.txt hi3.txt
```

But, then I've seen some Makefiles use `%.txt` as a wildcard. So I tried that next.

```
foo.txt: %.txt
    echo $^
```

However, this results in an error.

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target '%.txt', needed by 'foo.txt'.  Stop.
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

GNU Make 4.3

Comment: Your understanding is correct, %.go is the prerequisite. But if it doesn't exist, make will look for a rule to make it.   I have no idea why it doesn't understand %.

Comment: The percent sing is a `SunPro Make` feature from January 1986. So called pattern matching rules only apply in case of default rules and that require a percent on the left hand side as well.

Comment: Ah, okay. What is `%.png: %.svg` doing in this example? https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/make/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `make`, the percent sign is used for pattern matching, and it requires one in the target as well as (at least) one in the prerequisites:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

With this makefile, we specify that in order to build something whose file name ends with `.o`, you need to have a file that has the same prefix, but then ends with `.c` rather than `.o`

In order to be able to construct those rules, you obviously need to be able to refer to the target as well as the prerequisites; this is where the`$@` and `$<` variables come in. `$@` means 'the target of this rule', and `$<` means 'this rule's first listed prerequisite'. If you need to construct a command that uses *all* prerequisites (e.g., to link an executable), then you can use the variable `$^`:

```
%: %.o lib.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

If you combine the above two example makefile snippets in one makefile, and you have a file 'lib.c' with some common code that you want to use in a number of C programs in that same directory, then you can add any random `.c` file, say `foo.c`, and compile it into a program `foo` that also links in the code in `lib.c`, without requiring any changes to your makefile.

Note that it is also possible to have patterns with the same target, as long as the prerequisites are different; e.g., the following will work:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC).....
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX).....
```

that is, it will work as expected as long as you don't have any C++ source files in this directory that happen to have the same name (sans extension) as a C source file. If that does happen to be the case, the C++ version will be ignored and the C source will be compiled instead (because the C rule is listed first in the makefile)

For more info, see the [relevant section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) in the GNU make manual.